# Passing parameters to the event callbacks in itemview

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback

I am little new to backbone js however I want to pass some arguments to the event callback in 'events' section of an itemview. 
I know that call back can be added like {“event selector”: “callback”}. But the need is to pass arguments to the function "callback". I want to execute some local function of the itemview there in the callback.
For that I was thinking of passing reference to the itemview object to the callback so that its context shall be accessible. Is there any way to pass?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The context of the callback should be the view it was called from. So it should have access to all of the properties and methods defined for that itemview through 'this'.  In addition the callback gets passed the event that handled the click and the html item is available through event.currentTarget. Between these two you should be able to get the properties you need.

For example:

```
var itemView = Backbone.View.extend( {

events: {
  'click a': 'onAnchorClick'
},

property: 'test property',

render: function() {
  ...
},

onAnchorClick: function( event ) {
  console.log( 'Predefined property: ', this.property );
  console.log( 'object: ', event.currentTarget );
  return false;
}
} );
```